# How many floating point ops were performed worldwide over a time interval

Tags: floating-point, history

I am looking for information regarding the evolution of computing capability. Specifically I would like to know how many floating point operations were performed worldwide from, say, the deployment of ENIAC to the first moon landing... Or any other time interval before, say, the '80s. is this a question that I can estimate based on existing data?

Comment: That would be an interview question, about as good or bad as “how many ping-pong balls fit in a railway wagon” or “how many piano tuners in Seattle”.

Comment: It's not an interview question. I'm not doing an interview. It's for a rhetorical point in a presentation about computing ability of equipment that we have. But aside from that it's an interesting question anyway and it's on right.

Comment: It’s an interview question in the sense that I would expect you to come up with a reasonable answer in an interview.